# why pcl algothm so fast?

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello:
I want to write a VoxelGrid filter which can filter the center of the voxel. I just write the same as pcl source code in pcl/filters/include/pcl/filters/impl/filter.hpp. here is my code:

```
pcl::PointXYZI min_p,max_p;
pcl::getMinMax3D(*input_cloud_ptr_,min_p,max_p);

int dx = static_cast<int64_t>((max_p.x - min_p.x) * inverse_leaf_size_[0]) + 1;
int dy = static_cast<int64_t>((max_p.y - min_p.y) * inverse_leaf_size_[1]) + 1;
int dz = static_cast<int64_t>((max_p.z - min_p.z) * inverse_leaf_size_[2]) + 1;

if ((dx*dy*dz) > static_cast<int64_t>(std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max())) {
    std::cerr<<"leaf size is too small for the input cloud, Integer indices would overflow."<<std::endl;
    return;
}

// Compute the minimum and maximum bounding box values
min_bounding_idx_[0] = static_cast<int> (floor (min_p.x * inverse_leaf_size_[0]));
max_bounding_idx_[0] = static_cast<int> (floor (max_p.x * inverse_leaf_size_[0]));
min_bounding_idx_[1] = static_cast<int> (floor (min_p.y * inverse_leaf_size_[1]));
max_bounding_idx_[1] = static_cast<int> (floor (max_p.y * inverse_leaf_size_[1]));
min_bounding_idx_[2] = static_cast<int> (floor (min_p.z * inverse_leaf_size_[2]));
max_bounding_idx_[2] = static_cast<int> (floor (max_p.z * inverse_leaf_size_[2]));

div_bounding_ = max_bounding_idx_ - min_bounding_idx_ + Eigen::Vector3i::Ones ();

// Set up the division multiplier
divb_mul_ = Eigen::Vector3i (1, div_bounding_[0], div_bounding_[0] * div_bounding_[1]);

cloud_index_.clear();
cloud_index_.reserve (input_cloud_ptr_->size ());
out_cloud_ptr->clear();
voxel_idx_.clear();

for (int i = 0; i < input_cloud_ptr_->size(); ++i) {
    pcl::PointXYZI tmp_pt = input_cloud_ptr_->points[i];
    int ijk0 = static_cast<int> (floor (tmp_pt.x * inverse_leaf_size_[0]) - static_cast<float> (min_bounding_idx_[0]));
    int ijk1 = static_cast<int> (floor (tmp_pt.y * inverse_leaf_size_[1]) - static_cast<float> (min_bounding_idx_[1]));
    int ijk2 = static_cast<int> (floor (tmp_pt.z * inverse_leaf_size_[2]) - static_cast<float> (min_bounding_idx_[2]));

    // Compute the centroid leaf index
    int idx = ijk0 * divb_mul_[0] + ijk1 * divb_mul_[1] + ijk2 * divb_mul_[2];
    cloud_index_.push_back(CloudPointIndexIdx(static_cast<unsigned int> (idx), i));
    voxel_idx_.push_back(Eigen::Vector3i(ijk0,ijk1,ijk2));
}

std::sort (cloud_index_.begin (), cloud_index_.end (), std::less<CloudPointIndexIdx> ());

std::vector<Eigen::Vector3i>::iterator iter = std::unique(voxel_idx_.begin(),voxel_idx_.end());
voxel_idx_.erase(iter,voxel_idx_.end());
for(int i = 0;i < static_cast<int>(voxel_idx_.size());i++){
    int ijk0 = voxel_idx_[i][0];
    int ijk1 = voxel_idx_[i][1];
    int ijk2 = voxel_idx_[i][2];
    pcl::PointXYZI tmp_pt;
    tmp_pt.x = (ijk0 + static_cast<float> (min_bounding_idx_[0])) * leaf_size_[0] + leaf_size_[0] / 2.;
    tmp_pt.y = (ijk1 + static_cast<float> (min_bounding_idx_[1])) * leaf_size_[1] + leaf_size_[1] / 2.;
    tmp_pt.z = (ijk2 + static_cast<float> (min_bounding_idx_[2])) * leaf_size_[2] + leaf_size_[2] / 2.;
    out_cloud_ptr->push_back(tmp_pt);
}
```

I test my code and pcl with the same dataset, my code cost 50ms,and the pcl cost 2ms. I am just very curious why is so diffetrent. are there any skill ? I appreciate who can give me some answer! thx ~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270194/why-pcl-algothm-so-fast?/) by [mjjdick](https://answers.ros.org/users/31787/mjjdick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the source code is the same as PCL, you are probably compiling your code in *debug* mode.

You could try to recompile using

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

This will tell catkin to compile the code optimized for *release* (without *debug* symbols) and will likely execute faster.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjjdick](https://answers.ros.org/users/31787/mjjdick/) on 2017-09-04**:
you are right！thx very much！

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-05**:
@mjjdick: if you feel your question has been answered, please indicate that by ticking the checkmark to the left of the answer of @Martin Peris.